# Recompiling my code C#

Tags: c#, .net, crop, aforge

I learned that you can compile C# using  Visual Studio 2013 Express edition or Professional edition to compile c# code.  My code also contains AForge.NET Do I have to do anything special to compile with Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: You're looking for Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes it is, you will need it and visual studio to compile your application.  http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/downloads.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Visual Studio 2013 Express edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=40787) (free as in beer) or Professional edition to compile c# code.

Hiring - I guess, not a good place to ask. But I would suggest go back to Freelancer.